# Open Amazon link with Amazon App not Safari

Tags: ios, swift

I have an Amazon affiliate link (to a product) in the app I am developing (Swift 3).

Is there a possibility to let the user open the link with the Amazon App or let the user choose to open with Safari or Amazon App in case he doesn't have the Amazon App?

At this moment the link is always opened with Safari.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this without direct permission from Amazon.... and even then I am unsure. The only way I am currently aware of to handle this is in between a single user's/company's applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
com.amazon.mobile.shopping://www.amazon.com/gp/product/product-id
```

or

```
com.amazon.mobile.shopping.web://www.amazon.com/gp/product/product-id
```

If that doesn't work, search the web for `Amazon app url scheme` - you might find something more current.

Answer (score 0):

@DonMag solution seem to be outdated but was of big help !!

Here is the updated one :

```
com.amazon.mobile.shopping://www.amazon.com/products/B00KWFCV32/
```